# Best way for Node.js server to return an error before process runs out of heap memory

Tags: node.js, express

I'm running Node.js / Express server on a container with pretty strict memory constraints.

One of the endpoints I'd like to expose is a "batch" endpoint where a client can request a list of data objects in bulk from my data store. The individual objects vary in size, so it's difficult to set a hard limit on how many objects can be requested at one time. In *most* cases a client could request a large amount of objects without any issues, but it certain edge cases even requests for a small amount of objects will trigger an OOM error.

I'm familiar with Node's [`process.memoryUsage()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/process.html#processmemoryusage) & [`process.memoryUsage.rss()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/process.html#processmemoryusagerss), but I'm worried about the performance implications of constantly checking heap (or service) memory usage while serving an individual batch request.

In the longer term, I might consider using memory monitoring to bake in some automatic pagination for the endpoint. In the short term, however, I'd just like to be able to return an informative error to the client in the event that they are requesting too many data objects at a given time (rather than have the entire application crash with an OOM error).

Are there any more effective methods or tools I could be using to solve the problem instead?

Answer (score 0):

you have couple of options.

Options 1.
what is biggest object you have in store. I would say that you allow some {max object count} on api and set container memory to biggestObject x {max allowed objects size}. You can even have some pagination concept added if required where page size = {max object count}

Option 2.

Also using process.memoryUsage()  should be fine too. I don't believe it is a not a costly call unless you have read this somewhere. Before each object pull check current memory and go ahead only if safe amount of memory is available.The response in this case can contain only pulled data and lets client to pull remaining ids in next call. Implementable via some paging logic too.

options 3.
explore streams. This I will not be able to add much info for now.